# Moving individual particles within a Three.JS particle system

Tags: javascript, position, three.js, particle-system, particles

Running into a bit of a problem with Three.js. I'm currently trying to move particles within a particle system when each frame is rendered. No errors are being reported, but nothing is moving either! The example I took from the code at http://aerotwist.com/tutorials/creating-particles-with-three-js/ uses the syntax `particle.position.y`, but the JS console returns `Cannot set property 'y' of undefined` when I change the below code to mirror that. Any help or pointers on where I'm going wrong is much appreciated.

Full source code:

```
        var scene, camera, renderer, particleCount = 0, particleSystem, particles;

        init();
        animate();

        function init()
        {
            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
            scene.add(camera);
            camera.position.z = 5;

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            particleCount = 1800,
            particles = new THREE.Geometry();
            var pMaterial = new THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial({color: 0xFFFFFF, size: 0.5});

            for (var i = 0; i < particleCount; i++)
            {
                var pX = Math.random() * 500 - 250,
                    pY = Math.random() * 500 - 250,
                    pZ = Math.random() * 500 - 250,
                    particle = new THREE.Vector3(pX, pY, pZ);

                particles.vertices.push(particle);
            }

            particleSystem = new THREE.ParticleSystem(particles, pMaterial);
            scene.add(particleSystem);
        }

        function animate()
        {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            renderer.render(scene, camera);

            var pCount = particleCount;
            while (pCount--)
            {
                var particle = particles.vertices[pCount];
                particle.y = Math.random() * 500 - 250;
                particleSystem.geometry.vertices.needsUpdate = true;
            }

        }
```

Comment: You mention in your question that it is `particle.position.y` but in your code you write `particle.y`, is this a typo?

Comment: Thanks for the response -- particle.position.y returns an error for me; particle.y does not. Having looked at the documentation, Vector3s like 'particle' do seem to have 'y' as one of their properties.

Comment: Avoid outdated books and tutorials, and avoid examples from the net that link to old versions of the library. The example you learning from is using a version of three.js that is 3 years old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have to add `particleSystem.sortParticles = true;` after creating your `particleSystem`.

Comment: Thanks -- that, together with using particle.setY() rather than particle.y, seems to have done the trick.

Comment: No problem, although it worked for me using `particle.y` - I'm not sure which is the preferred method =)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered exactly the same issue in the same tutorial but, using ThreeJS 86, I needed neither the `setY()` nor the `particleSystem.sortParticles = true;` but `particleSystem.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;` (*not* `particleSystem.geometry.vertices.needsUpdate = true;`).